# How to find out if the caret exists [in opera]?

Tags: c#, winapi, opera, ui-automation

I'm trying to solve following task: 
I have OPERA browser and I want  to find out, whether caret (text cursor) exist at any time. For example, I click on address bar, and I want to know that the caret is blinking now. Then I click on empty place on the page and I know that there is no caret exists.

In other words I want to define that some text element is in focus now.

I know how to solve this task in many applications, some of them uses standard windows controls such as Edit, so I can obtain focused window and check it's class with WinApi.

In other applications, where controls are rendering without native windows, I can obtain this with Automation UI.

But for my regret Opera has only one main window and doesn't provide access for UI automation technology.

So, does anybody know how approach my goal?)

EDIT:

Thanks for Eric Brown, this is solution of problem:

```
// ConsoleForMSAA.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <OleAcc.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib, "oleacc.lib")

void ProcessCaretPos(HWND hwnd);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    for (;;)
    {
        // active toplevel window
        HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();

        // current thread
        DWORD currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

        DWORD targetThreadId, targetProcessId;

        // target process and thread
        targetThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &targetProcessId); 

        // attach current thread to target thread messaging queue
        BOOL attached = AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, targetThreadId, true);

        // что это даст? Мы участвуем в обработке сообщений того потока
        // и все сис. вызовы, которые мы сделаем, будут посланы от имени того потока.
        if (attached)
        {
            try
            {
                // get focused window handle (focused child that of toplevel window)
                HWND targetWindow = GetFocus();

                // some procedure 
                ProcessCaretPos(targetWindow);
            }
            catch(...) {;}

            AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, targetThreadId, false);
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

// 
void ProcessCaretPos(HWND hwnd)
{
    IAccessible *pAccCaret = NULL;

    VARIANT varCaret;
    RECT rcCaret;
    varCaret.vt = VT_I4;
    varCaret.lVal = CHILDID_SELF;

    if (SUCCEEDED(AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_CARET, IID_IAccessible, (void **)&pAccCaret)))
    {
        HRESULT hr = pAccCaret->accLocation( &rcCaret.left, &rcCaret.top, &rcCaret.right, &rcCaret.bottom, varCaret);

        if (!hr)
        {
            std::cout << "caret positon: " << rcCaret.left << " " << rcCaret.top << " " << rcCaret.right << " " << rcCaret.bottom << "\n";
        }
        else
            std::cout << "there is nothing carets" << "\n"; 

        pAccCaret->Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably out of luck.  However, if Opera uses the system caret (which it might not; IE doesn't, for example), you can *try* using MSAA to query the system caret location:

```
IAccessible *pAccCaret = NULL;

VARIANT varCaret;
RECT rcCaret;
varCaret.vt = VT_I4;
varCaret.lVal = CHILDID_SELF;

if (SUCCEEDED(AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_CARET, IID_IAccessible, (void **)&pAccCaret)))
{
     hr = pAccCaret->accLocation( &rcCaret.left, &rcCaret.top, &rcCaret.right, &rcCaret.bottom, varCaret);

     pAccCaret->Release();
}
```

Comment: Eric Brown, thank you! I tried it in opera and it has worked! Furthermore I tried this code for IE explorer and it has worked too! But in case of IE and many other programs I had to obtain focused element of toplevel window before I can use this code.

Comment: [GetGuiThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506(v=vs.85).aspx) will return the foreground toplevel window.

Comment: Sorry, there was not question) I have used functions GetForeground(), GetWindowProcessThreadId(), AttachToThread() and GetFocus(). I think that function GetGuiThreadInfo isn't suitable for my purpose, because I want to retrieve firstly ThreadId from mainWindow and then obtain focused element using attach to founded threadId.

Comment: If by AttachToThread() you mean `AttachThreadInput`, [please stop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/01/8795860.aspx).  `GetGuiThreadInfo` returns exactly the same data and doesn't have all sorts of unexpected requirements.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your advice, but there is a very bad quality video, so I can't understand why using AttachThreadInput is bad way. Can you tell me? P.S. I tried GetGuiThreadInfo and it works but I dislike that it needs to fill CbSize field by sizeof(this structure). So I have to write unsafe construct or write magic digits such as 48 ))

Comment: Unless both threads are aware that the queues are attached, use of `AttachThreadInput` tends to cause deadlocks and hangs, as the linked message describes.  As for `GetGuiThreadInfo`, what's wrong with `Marshal.SizeOf()`?